# Up navigation issue with PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, preferencefragment

I am learning to have a proper back navigation with `Fragment`s.

It works fine so far, but not with my `PreferenceFragment`.

When my user clicks on Settings, it does the following:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, new SettingsFragment())
                .addToBackStack("SettingsFragment")
                .commit();
```

But for some reason `getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()` returns 0 right after this snippet.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`commit()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit()) description:

> Schedules a commit of this transaction. The commit **does not happen immediately**; it will be scheduled as work on the main thread to be done the next time that thread is ready.

This means that if you put `getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()` right after you commit the transaction, it will show the *old* number of entries, since the current transaction hasn't been executed yet.